# How do I sync Google Calendar with my Outlook Calendar?

Tags: outlook, google-calendar, synchronization

At work we use Outlook, but I want an easy way to sync it with my private Google Calendar.

However, I tried looking at the Outlook (2010) settings and couldn't find how to make a link.

So how do I sync my Google Calendar with my Outlook one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Google's Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955):

> Google Calendar Sync allows you to sync events between Google Calendar and Microsoft Outlook Calendar. You'll be able to determine the direction of information flow, as well as the sync frequency. Staying on top of your Google Calendar and Microsoft Outlook Calendar events has never been easier! Here's some good information to know to help you get started with Google Calendar Sync.

It lists as only being compatible with Outlook 2003 and 2007, so I'm not sure if it works with Outlook 2010.

Comment: It doesn't (yet) work with 2010, though there might have been a recent update

Comment: "Currently, Google Calendar Sync is only compatible with Microsoft Outlook versions 2003 and 2007, and operating systems Windows XP and Windows Vista"

Comment: At work I run Calendar Sync in Windows XP mode with Outlook 2007 as on my PC I have Win 7 and Outlook 2010. It works but I wouldn't really recommend it...

Comment: Sigh, Google is killing Calendar Sync for free users. http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936#gcs

Answer (score 2):

Google has a tool to help you with this called [Google Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955)

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=89955

Comment: No longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar Sync, as others have suggested, can work with Outlook 2003 and 2007.
However, I have found that Google Calendar Sync is kinda buggy and has sometimes corrupted my data. Further, it does not work if your calendar is huge like mine. And Google does not seem particularly committed to supporting this product.

I have now switched to a software called [gSyncit](http://www.daveswebsite.com/software/gsync/) and am quite happy with it.
It costs $15.
It supports sync for contacts, calendars, tasks across multiple google accounts.
I have used it with Outlook 2003 as well as Outlook 2007. It claims compatibility with Outlook 2010, but I have no first hand experience with Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SyncMyCal](http://www.syncmycal.com/).  Google Calendar Sync does not support (http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98565) 64 bit OS so this is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that following [this guide from Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) only partially works. After copy-pasting the private calendar link into MS Outlook 2013, Outlook throws the error

> Cannot verify or add the Internet Calendar in Outlook. Verify the link is a valid calendar link

The workaround (how simple can it be?) I found was to:

- Go to your calendar settings in Google Calendar (by clicking the arrow next to the calendar you want to share, under the "My Calendars" menu)
- Copy the link address behind the iCAL logo next to "Private Address" (i.e.: right click and select copy url) [image: Private Address ICAL]
- Paste the link in a new browser tab. This will download a .ics file.
- Double click that file. Outlook will open it and automatically add your Google calendar as a new calendar.